# Cannot call button click event using javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a file upload and a button in my asp.

this is my aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="stage" runat="server" cssClass="containment-wrapper" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
     <asp:Image ID="imgBrowse" runat="server" Height="375px" Width="640px" ImageUrl="Image/ClickHere.png" style="cursor:pointer"/>
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_IE" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
     <asp:Button ID="btn_UploadHandler" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn_UploadHandler_Click" style="display:none;"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to fire the click event when the `FileUpload_IE` has been change. This is my js file:

```
$("#stage").click(function () {
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    $('#FileUpload_IE')[0].click();       
}
});


 $("#FileUpload_IE").on("change", function (e) {
    $("#btn_UploadHandler").click();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The code has error in jquery 1.10.2 which is   `elem[ type ]();` is access denied.

Comment: IE version?, In IE9 there is a problem when the file browser was shown by clicking another element(other than the file input control itself).. not sure about IE10.. in IE11 it works fine... I didn't get any solution for that so In IE9&IE10 instead of showing the image we ended by showing the file control itself

Comment: If you select the file by clicking the file control instead of the image it should work fine

Comment: then still the problem might exists... I didn't test in IE8 since it is no longer supported in my project.... can you remove the hidden property for the file control and check

Comment: I had looked for a solution for a while... but didn't find any that suits my need.... if you find one please let me know

Comment: Sorry, I added some scripts in my question. When I remove the `$('#FileUpload_IE')[0].click();` the  `$("#btn_UploadHandler").click();` is working but I need to click the file upload control.